# FormData object is empty in asp.net mvc5 controller when ie11 browser is used to send request data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-11

Currently my application logic works correctly on Chrome and Firefox browser, but for some reason it doesn't work in the same way on IE11 browser. I have following function which is called from related with it html button :

```
    function sendStatus(url, status, comment) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('status', status);
    formData.append('comment', comment);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        error: showErrorMessage,
        success: showPreview
    });
```

and if request are coming to server from IE11, then HttpContext.Request.Form property doesn't include anything placed into formData. The same request called from Chrome/Firefox include everything declare in formdata object. Is there anything that I need to change in that code or provide some additional logic for ie11 browser ?

Comment: Have you used F12 devtools in IE 11 to check if there's any error in console? I made a test with your code snippet and it works well in IE 11. I receive the formData in the backend using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["status"]`. What are the data "status" and "comment" look like in your code? I don't know if it's related with the data value.